# How do I specify a unicode message body in a Twilio SMS request?

Tags: javascript, unicode, twilio

[According to Twilio](http://forum.twilio.com/twilio/topics/spanish_sms_inbound_outbound#reply_9497615), they now support unicode characters in their RESTful SMS interface. However, it's not clear to me how I can take advantage of this in Javascript (this is in Node).

When I send SMS messages with Spanish translations (defaulting to UTF-8), the message will get chopped into three messages on the recipients phone. I'm guessing that the root cause is I need to send a unicode message body in the request.

How can I convert a Javascript string into unicode? I've attempted a character-by-character translation...

```
function toUnicode(theString) {
  var unicodeString = '';
  for (var i=0; i < theString.length; i++) {
    var theUnicode = theString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16).toUpperCase();
    while (theUnicode.length < 4) {
      theUnicode = '0' + theUnicode;
    }
    theUnicode = '\\u' + theUnicode;
    unicodeString += theUnicode;
  }
  return unicodeString;
}
```

... but that produces a message body that is interpreted as being longer then the 160 character limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending the message as Unicode then that requires a 16 bit encoding.  The limit for  a 16 bit encoding in SMS is 70 characters. That is because the SMS signaling protocol is limited to 140 octets, which translates to the normal 160 characters if you are using 7 bit encoding. This is a restriction of the SMS protocol, not Twilio.  I was not sure if you question was how to send in Unicode, or why does it break up my message.

Comment: you're right that there are two questions buried in there. your encoding answer helps shed some light - the code snippet i use for converting to unicode takes 34 characters and produces 204 characters of unicode.

Comment: Since you are using Javascript the convention used for Unicode is the prefix "/u" followed by a 4 digit hexadecimal value that represents the character, so that will be 6 characters in Javascript to represent 1 Unicode character (34 x 6 = 204). But it should still be 16 bits per character for Unicode once it is in the Twilio API. Is the Twilio API handling the Unicode characters from your Javascript correctly when the message is displayed?  Is it breaking the message at 70 characters?

Comment: The Twilio API does not seem to recognize it as Unicode - it's as if the characters are being counted first because it gets rejected by the API due to length.